# Android Wifi P2P without asking user

Tags: java, android, wifi, p2p

is there a possibility to let an Android app communicate over Wifi P2P with other device, wich has the same app running, without asking the user to communicate for every device.
The problem is: I want to make a multiplayer game for many users on the same time and the app should not ask everyone to pair the devices with the others. It should be done in background, without showing messages to the users.

Is this possible?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Android Developer Forum:

- You can connect to WiFi P2P using [android.net.wifi.p2p](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/package-summary.html)
- You need to set below in manifest file.

> ```
> <manifest>
>     uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi.direct" />
>     ...
> </manifest
> ```

- Use [discoverPeers()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html#discoverPeers(android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel,%20android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ActionListener)) and [connect()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html#connect(android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel,%20android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pConfig,%20android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ActionListener)) to discover and connect to peers.

Nowhere the page states that you would need additional passcodes from user to do so.

Check the demo from Google [here](http://developer.android.com/samples/index.html)

Comment: Thx for your answer, i will try it. I dont have expected getting an reply after nearly a year :)